# Ways or services to host android app back end (for push)

Tags: android, csv, cloud, push, saas

I just had a developer create a menu app for my retail store.  We sell 200 flavors of juice and the purpose is for the customer to search based on ingredients.

The back end is used to upload csv files with each flavor and all its ingredients. EX: Flavor X has Mango, orange and melon. Flavor Y has melon and banana. - The customer can search for melon flavors and the app will propagate both X and Y flavors as options.

The developer locked me into and SAAS (software as service) model and expects me to pay him a monthly fee for the cloud back end.  When I contested to this, he said there is no other way except to build my own cloud and its very expensive.  I believe he may be taking advantage of my lack of knowledge but I am not sure.

Can anyone suggest a free or inexpensive way to host a back end to store my csv files? At which point I can have the app code written to direct there and download the csv.

I already paid a couple thousand to make my app and I'm not monotising it, just using it for convenience and cannot afford to pay $50/month in addition.

What are my options here?

Comment: Check for http://www.baasbox.com/cloudservice/pricingplan and https://backendless.com/pricing/.
I use baasbox's open source cloud software to use my own PC as mBAAS provider. So, I pay nothing more than internet chrages.

Answer (score 0):

For push notifications there is a private service pushwoosh.check out here https://www.pushwoosh.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Drive which is available for any gmail account (so you could try to connect yours to store your app csv files). Also every gmail account has other possibilities to store files and Data Bases for free with some limitations. You could read more about it in your own gmail acc.
As for Cloud service it is really not for free and it really has monthly fee.
Another option is to host your files on some free hosting service which has its own limitations (professional hosts are monthly fee based too).
I cant see anything about push (actually push is for iOS) or GCM (which is Android Google Cloud Message) in your post so I assume there is no GCM used in app. Cuz if you need GCM system then you need to host a server with backend software to send GCMs to your app users. Actually there is a bunch of push/GCM services available like [urbanairship](http://urbanairship.com/) and others but all of it are not for free and monthly fee based (once again).
Also take a look at [Parse.com](http://parse.com)

Answer (score 0):

If the back end is truly just a file repository for CSV files, you can simply add the files to your website (if you have one) and access them through there. You don't need to link to those files anywhere, the files will just live there to be accessed by your application. If you don't have a website, it's quite easy to get some ad-driven hosting for free.

If read access to your data needs to be protected, then this becomes a slightly more complex story that would affect how your app code is written.